# Linux kernel driver : polling on hardware register

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, embedded, linux-device-driver

I'm writing a Linux driver that aims to delegate some work to hardware accelerators. My driver writes some registers and memories to tell the hardware to do its job. Once the hardware is done, it will indicate so by setting a status register to 1. I do realize this is not how it should be done and that IRQ should be used instead and I'm planning to do so. But for now, I'm willing to do some polling on that register. And here I am, asking you smart people what's the best way to do so.

My hardware registers are mapped into kernel space using `ioremap()` and here is the code I'm struggling with :

```c
int mailbox_request(const uint32_t *request, size_t request_size, struct mailbox_reply *reply)
{
    size_t i;
    int retval = 0;

    if(down_interruptible(&sem))
        return -ERESTARTSYS;

    for(i = 0; i < request_size; i++)
        iowrite32(mailbox + FIFO_OFFSET, request[i]);

    iowrite32(mailbox + CONTROL_OFFSET, 1);

    // WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE TO WAIT FOR THE RESULT ?
    // while(ioread32(mailbox + STATUS_OFFSET) != 1); // better not do that...

    reply->data = ioread32(mailbox + RESULT_OFFSET);

out:
    up(&sem);
    return retval;
}
```

My first idea was to use a workqueue and a waitqueue as follow :

```c
static DECLARE_WORK(workqueue, mailbox_polling_result);
static DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD(wq);

static void mailbox_polling_result(struct work_struct *work)
{
    while(ioread32(mailbox + STATUS_OFFSET) != 1)
        msleep_interruptible(100);

    wake_up_interruptible(&wq);
}

int mailbox_request(const uint32_t *request, size_t request_size, struct mailbox_reply *reply)
{
    [...]
    schedule_work(&workqueue);
    wait_event_interruptible(wq, ioread32(mailbox + STATUS_OFFSET) == 1);
    [...]
}
```

I'm not sure this is relevant, but just in case : the `mailbox_request` function won't necessarily be called from a process context. It might very well be called by the kernel itself. I read somewhere that workqueues are executed in a process context, that's why I'm telling you about that, to be sure this is not an issue.

Then I was wondering if the {work,wait}queue way of doing was not a bit overkill for what I'm trying to achieve ? I read somewhere about the `schedule()` function and I have to admit this a bit obscure to me. Would you consider that to be ok :

```c
int mailbox_request(const uint32_t *request, size_t request_size, struct mailbox_reply *reply)
{
    [...]
    while(ioread32(mailbox + STATUS_OFFSET) != 1) {
        schedule(); // or maybe some interruptible_sleep ?
    }
    [...]
}
```

The idea being to prevent the kernel from being stuck if it has better things to do. If you think of better ways to do that, I'd be glad to read about it !

Comment: `readx_poll_timeout()` and derivatives is a cheapest method to achieve that without using work queue. What you are describing is implemented in many places in the kernel, e.g.  https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.13-rc2/source/drivers/platform/x86/intel_scu_ipc.c#L265.

Comment: despite being kernel 4.0+, `readx_poll_timeout` looks nice indeed ! However, unless I'm missing something, it does not seem to be interruptible, meaning the kernel will be stuck until a result is returned. [It appears to be a simple sleep/timeout mecanism](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.0.9/source/include/linux/iopoll.h#L43).

Comment: @ShellCode If by "stuck" you mean busy waiting, then specifying a non-zero `sleep_us` value will allow it to sleep for a period between reads. It's just that the sleep period will be non-interruptible. (But your current `mailbox_polling_result` idea doesn't do anything special if the `msleep_interruptible` call is interrupted anyway - it just rechecks the status register again earlier than it would have done if the `msleep_interruptible` ran to completion.)

Comment: Having `mailbox_request` delegate the "poll until complete" snippet to a work-item has the effect of potentially delaying the handling of other work items, so it is better to do the "poll until complete" snippet directly in `mailbox_request` since it has to wait for the result anyway.

Comment: @IanAbbott thanks for your answer ! If I do as you say (putting the while loop in the main body of the function), will the kernel still be able to process other things while waiting for the mailbox ? Or will the sleep monopolize a whole CPU core until the loop comes to an end ?

Comment: `*sleep*()` family of functions are aware of the scheduling. That's why `readx_poll_timeout()` or derivatives is good enough to wait for the status bit(s) from the hardware register.

Comment: Spending a lot of time in a work item function is a bad idea because there are a limited number of worker threads. Rather than using `msleep` in a work item function, it is better to use the "delayed work" API and have the work item function reschedule itself to be re-run after a suitable delay.

Comment: Thanks guys, it's clear now